# local variable 'model_prediction' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

[Build a web App to deploy letter recognition model ,but have errors please help][1]

```
def foo():
  if some_condition:
    try:
      x = bar()  # bar may throw a ValueError
      y = 2
    except ValueError:
      return "bla bla message"
  return baz(x, y)
```

I'm getting the error: local variable 'y' referenced before assignment

Comment: Instead of linking to the code, the right approach for StackOverflow questions is to post the relevant code directly in the question. That way we don't have to follow links, and your question will be immortal, since the contents at the target link may change at any time.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for information on how to ask a question that will lead to good answers.

Answer (score 1):

Your variable definitions are in the `if some_condition` conditional statement but your return statement is not... Consequently if `some_condition` is false, neither `x` nor `y` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

If line 2 is `False`, `y` is not set. Hence the message. You should assign some default value for `y`:

```
def foo():
  y = some_default_value
  if True:
    try:
      x = bar()  # bar may throw a ValueError
      y = 2
    except ValueError:
      return "bla bla message"
  return baz(x, y)
```